# Getting jSignature to work with Twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, digital-signature

I am currently trying to get jSignature ( a plugin to capture signatures) to work inside the twitter bootstrap modals. For some reason the signature box is getting shrunk to fit inside the modal and making the signature not work properly. Here is a jsFiddle for reference http://jsfiddle.net/someyoungideas/3B3jS/ .

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p id="signature"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: When adjusting the width of the embedded html in the fiddle, the signature works again. I tried adding a `min-height`, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 13):

This seems to work for me!

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {    
  $("#signature").jSignature();
  $("#signature").resize();
});
```

There have been some cases where I've needed to wrap both the jSignature initialization and resize in a timeout, but I think it mostly depends on the styling a processes of the modal itself.

Comment: I had the same issue using a collapse, same style fix: '$('#collapsedPanel').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
 $("#signature").resize();
});'

Answer (score 2):

jSignature fits itself to the `div` inside which it is initialized. In other words, if the `div` with id `signature` is measured to be 0x0 at the time jSignature is initialized, it's initialized as that.

When page/window is resized, which results in the `div` resizing, jSignature readjusts its size to fit the div again. However, this auto-resize works **only when windows resizes** not when windows stays the same but `div` resizes.

Now, why is this important?

When you init jSignature, you init it against a hidden `div`. Its size is 0x0 at this stage.

- jSignature allows you to specify the size in options Object.  - simple but ugly solution
- You could set a hard size (width and height) to the `signature` `div`. - simple but ugly solution.
- You could init jSignature **after** the `signature` `div` becomes visible and obtains its size. - suggested solution as this way jSignature will fit itself within the modal.

Outdated: http://jsfiddle.net/3B3jS/6/

```
$("#myModal")
// .on('show', function() {
//     console.log('Modal will be shown');
// })
.on('shown', function() {
    // consider checking if the sig widget is already there and if not:
    $("#signature").jSignature()
})
// .on('hide', function() {
//     console.log('Modal will be hidden');
// })
// .on('hidden', function() {
//     console.log('Modal is hidden');
// })
```

Comment: This works also when doing a "regular" show/hide on the `div` (i.e. without Bootstrap).